# Some of the user profile fields on registration page not showing in user edit page

Tags: users

I have customized user profile edit page as page-user-edit.tpl.php in drupal 6 and created custom fields in user profiles like COMPANY SIZE with radio buttons, NO OF EMPLOYEES  etc.

It is configured to display these field during registration based on role. It works well. My problem is these fields are not being displayed on user edit page (user/*/edit). Is there any way i can display the fields on user edit page to update values.

Here is my code on page-user-edit.tpl.php

```
<div id="container">
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="page_tp">

<?php if(arg(0) == 'user' && arg(3) == 'profile' && arg(1) != '0' && trim($user->roles[3]) == 'Corporate Profile'  ){ ?>

<?php print $help; ?> <?php print_r($content); ?>

<?php } ?>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like a problem with conditionals. Can you tell us how did you make them conditional based on role?

Comment: <?php if(arg(0) == 'user' && arg(3) == 'profile' && arg(1) != '0' && trim($user->roles[3]) == 'Corporate Profile'  ){ ?><?php print_r($content); ?><?php } ?> Here is my code to print the content based on role. but the fields from content profile fields are shown in user edit profile page.

Comment: Please edit this into a question itself. Also, please include not only the line itself, but meaningful portion of code, ie whole hook implementation or significant part of tpl file (with filename information included, as in case of tpl it matters).

Comment: @Molot i have edited and included the code in question itself and ignore if its clear for you this is the code i have implemented in page-user-edit.tpl.php

Comment: How you have created custom fields for user registration?

Comment: @jayendra - yes i have created fields in admin->user->profile->Add new field -> checkbox

Comment: It will create fields as category sub tabs in user profile page.

Comment: i don't understand where the category sub tabs appear in user profile page ? page-user-edit.tpl.php is only for user profile edit page, i didn't print any tabs here. Can you tell me more clearly it will help for me to get the fields.Thanks

Comment: If you are not seeing tabs, then you need to print `$tabs2` and `$tabs` variable in your `page-user-edit.tpl.php` file.

Comment: yes i can see the tab while print $tabs; and i got "VIEW,EDIT,MEMBERSHIP,ORDER HISTORY,MY SIGNUPS" tabs here i need the field to be in EDIT tab right ? but i cant see any user profile field in it and there is no changes on printing $tabs2.

Answer (score 0):

I think the custom fields comes under a new tab. The tab name would be the value you given in the category field . please check

Comment: You may correct @nabil i did checked that too . I have created my fields under category "COMPANY" but there is no name like "COMPANY" in tabs.?